# Make a bar chart of a result

Tags: python, spotify

I have to do a barchart of the top 10 artists with the most songs on Spotify with Python.

I have the top 10 thanks to this code :

```
df.artists.value_counts()[:10]
```

Output is :

```
['Эрнест Хемингуэй']      1215
['Francisco Canaro']       938
['Эрих Мария Ремарк']      781
['Ignacio Corsini']        620
['Frank Sinatra']          592
['Bob Dylan']              539
['The Rolling Stones']     512
['Johnny Cash']            502
['The Beach Boys']         491
['Elvis Presley']          488
Name: artists, dtype: int64
```

I tried this code to get a barchart :

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.bar(df_merge,
             x='artists', y='cumsum',
             color='artists',
             animation_frame='year', animation_group='year',
             range_y=[0,1000],
             title='Artists with Most Number of Songs')
fig.show()
```

But it doesn't work, I have "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotly'"

Do someone knows why?

Comment: It seems like you don't have plotly installed. Try "pip install plotly".

Comment: I tried and I have :   pip install plotly
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I was talking about writing it into your terminal.

Comment: If you have anaconda download it using that. It will be simple

Comment: ```pip install plotly==4.13.0``` try this using pip though

Answer (score 0):

You need to install plotly

On the machine you are running your code open a terminal and run, `pip install plotly`